# How to Display Underlined Text in a Button : iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to display the mail ID in my view such that clicking the mail ID should open the mail composer view.

I want to display the button text as underlined to show it is a hyperlink and for the button click event to call the mail composer view. At present, I am not able to show the button text underlined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UILabel to implement this Tack look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) for display underline label. And add TapGestureRecognizer to label and in that TapGestureRecognizer method implement code to show MailComposer.